# Equivalent of Java ArrayList in Objective-C

Tags: java, ios, objective-c, generics, collections

In Objective-C what is equivalent of `List<Products> cartProduct = new ArrayList();`. I used NSMutableArray but that is different than Java ArrayList.

Comment: How is it different? What are you trying to do that `NSMutableArray` can't?

Comment: i want to do collection with NSMUtableArray how it can be possible

Comment: `NSMutableArray arr = [NSMutableArray array];` then `[arr addObject:thing];` Is this not what you are looking for?

Comment: There's no generics in Obj-C so your question is irrelevant. If you want to use generic collections, you should move to Swift.

Comment: @orxelm thanks i like your answer

Comment: I'm not that familiar with Java. What is the key to an ArrayList? Is it a numeric index or does it use a String or some other object as the key? If it's a numeric index then a mutable array is the closest type. If it uses some other type of key then a mutable dictionary is the closest type.

Comment: @DuncanC it is class eg. List<Product>cartProduct=new ArrayList(); in this case cartProductis a arraylist of type class Product

Comment: I don't know the Java terms. That's why I asked specific questions, which you failed to answer.

Answer (score 5):

It sounds to me like Java `ArrayLists` use generics.

Objective-C does not have true support for generics. (Swift does. You may want to use Swift instead.)

Objective-C's collection classes (`NSArray` and `NSMutableArray`) are heterogeneous. They can contain a mixture of objects of different types. However, a recent addition to the language adds a very thin layer of generic support.

You'd use syntax like this:

```
NSMutableArray <Products *> *cartProduct;
```

That syntax only adds compile-time type checking. It tells the compiler that `cartProduct` is a mutable array that should only contain objects of type `Products`, so you get warnings when you to add/fetch objects of other types from the array, but the array will still take objects of any type at runtime.

I found [**this link**](http://www.miqu.me/blog/2015/06/09/adopting-objectivec-generics/) explaining more about Objective-C's "lightweight" support for generics. It seems pretty clear and well written.